# i have a samsung alpha. where the memory is full and storage space running out.. but it gets complicated

Tags: insufficient-memory

I have a *Samsung Alpha.35gb* – and I'm not the most mobile savvy person.

Recently I keep getting 2 messages, one saying 'device memory full' (unable to receive sms/mms messages) and the other tells me storage space running out. When I check where most of the full memory is coming from, it points to the APP INFO.contact storage version 4.4.4 says I have over 12GB!!? When I open contact space I have over 400 contacts that have no name?

What is this and how can I get rid of these? I try deleting and they don't delete! As a result my phone is not reacting.

Comment: First-aid on the "insufficient storage" issue can be found in our [insufficient-memory tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info). As you've already identified the culprit (and hoping you've got a backup of your "good contacts"), to clear that up you could go to *Settings › Apps,* find the mentioned app, force-stop it (if that button is enabled), and clear its cache and data. Right after that, reboot. Note that will not only clear those "over 400 contacts without name", but *all* of them.